# Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be continuous from $(X,d_{X})$ to $(Y,d_{Y})$. Let $E$ be any connected subset of $X$. Then $f(E)$ is also connected.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map from one metric space $(X,d_{X})$ to another $(Y,d_{Y})$. Let $E$ be any connected subset of $X$. Then $f(E)$ is also connected.

**My solution**

Suppose otherwise that $f(E)$ is disconnected. Thus $f(E) = U\cup V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open, disjoint and nonempty sets.

Since $E \subseteq f^{-1}(U\cup V) = f^{-1}(U)\cup f^{-1}(V)$ where $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are open, nonempty and disjoint, we conclude that $E$ is disconnected, which is a contradiction. Consequently, the proposed result holds.

Am I reasoning correctly? Could someone provide an alternative way to prove it?

Comment: In general, we have $E\subseteq f^{-1}(U\cup V)$ instead of equality in your second paragraph because $f$ may not be injective. You also need the assumption that both $U$ and $V$ are non-empty.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you provide another way to approach it?

Comment: Your approach is fine. Just change the equality to a inclusion $E\subseteq f^{-1}(U\cup V)$.

Comment: Same comment for $f(E)$. It should be a subset of $U\cup V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am giving two ways to approach this problem.

**Definition** A (metric) space $X$ is said to be connected if the only sets which are both open and closed in $X$ are  $\phi$ and the full space $X$ , when $X$ is a metric space.

**Theorem**-Let $X$ be a connected (metric) space and $g: X \to Y$ be a continuous map. Then $g(X)$ is connected.

**Proof(1)**-Let $f: g(X)\to \{±1\}$ be a continuous function on  $f(X)$. Since $fog: X \to \{±1\}$ is continuous and $X$ is connected, it follows that $fog$  is a constant on $X$. Hence $f$ is a constant on $g(X)$. Therefore $g(X)$ is connected.

**Proof(2)** Assume that $g(X)$ is not connected. Then there exists nonempty proper subset $V\subset g(X)$ which is both open and closed in $g(X)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(V)$ and $g^{-1}(g(X)-V)$ are both nonempty, closed and open in $X$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $X$ is connected.